# Diferencias entre los tipos de datos DateTIme y DateTime2 en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Aunque apareció en la edición 2008 de SQL Server, jamás he utilizado el tipo `datetime2`. Me he cruzado con él en algún proyecto pero no he tenido interés hasta hoy en saber qué diferencias y ventajas puede tener sobre el tipo clásico `datetime`.

¿Se utilizan por igual? ¿Hay uno mejor que el otro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claramente deberíamos utilizar exclusivamente el tipo `datetime2`. Esto es debido a que trae claras ventajas.

- `Datetime2` cumple con el estándar ISO 8601
- `Datetime` tiene un rango de fechas entre 1753 y 9999 mientras que `datetime2` va desde el año 1 hasta 9999.
- `Datetime2` es más preciso (100 nanosegundos) por 3,33 milisegundos de `datetime`.
- Podemos especificar la precisión con la que queremos trabajar.

  DateTime() = DateTime2(3)
- En idénticas circunstancias, `datetime2` ocupa menos espacio que un `datetime` (8 bytes): 6 bytes para precisiones de menos de 4, 7 bytes para precisiones de 3 o 4, 8 bytes para el resto de precisiones
- No hay diferencias en el trato que le da `System.DateTime` en .NET. La versión de `DateTime` de .NET tiene un rango y una precisión similar a la de `datetime2` de SQL.
- Cuando se pasa por parámetros en .NET a un `SqlCommand`, es necesario especificar que se trata de un `System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2` puesto que por defecto .NET toma el tipo `System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2`.
- `Datetime2` es más rápido al utilizarse como filtro en un `WHERE`

Por otra parte, se han reportado varias librerías de acceso a datos que son incompatibles con `datetime2` (ODBC, OLEDB, JDBC, …)

Para ver las diferencia podemos hacerlo con un código muy simple

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    sdt smalldatetime,
    dt datetime,
    dt20 datetime2(0),
    dt27 datetime2(7)
)

INSERT @temp
SELECT getdate(),getdate(),getdate(),getdate()

SELECT sdt,DATALENGTH(sdt) as sdt_bytes,
    dt,DATALENGTH(dt) as dt_bytes,
    dt20,DATALENGTH(dt20) as dt20_bytes,
    dt27, DATALENGTH(dt27) as dt27_bytes FROM @temp
```